# Normal Distribution - variance of minimal MSE (mean squared error)

Tags: statistics, optimization, normal-distribution

We are given $n$ normally distributed random variables $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. We have
\begin{align}
S^2 = C \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2
\end{align} 
We want to find $C$, such that the variance has minimal MSE. Now, I already have that,
\begin{align}
E(S^2)=C \, (n-1) \,\sigma ^2,
\end{align}
but I don't see how I would calculate $\operatorname{var}(S^2)$ to find the $\operatorname{MSE}(S^2)$ (and minimize it with respect to $C$). Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use the fact that $S^2/C\sigma^2\sim \chi^2_{(n-1)}$ to compute the variance of $S^2$.

Comment: True. So I get for the variance var$(S^2)=2 \, C^2\, \sigma ^2 \, (n-1)$ and therefore for the MSE to be minimal $C$ should be $C=(n+1)^{-1}$.

Thank you for the hint!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860289/minimum-mean-squared-error-of-an-estimator-of-the-variance-of-the-normal-distrib/.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variance with minimal MSE in normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250333/variance-with-minimal-mse-in-normal-distribution)