# Smallest MSE among estimators of the form cU for Normal Distribution

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Let $X_{1},...,X_{n}$ be a random sample from $n(\mu ,\sigma ^{2})$ where $\mu$, $\sigma$ are both unknown and $n\geq 2$. Denote $U=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \bar{X})^2$. Let $V=cU$ be an estimator of $\sigma ^{2}$ where c is a positive constant. I found the MSE to be

$$MSE (V)=\frac{2\sigma^4}{n+1}$$

Now, I need help with finding the estimator which has the smallest MSE among estimators of the forms $cU$. How do I go about it?

Comment: Your MSE of $V$ doesn't depend on $c$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860289/minimum-mean-squared-error-of-an-estimator-of-the-variance-of-the-normal-distrib/.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth, it depends on c. I found c to be 1/(n+1).

Comment: If you already minimised the MSE of $cU$, there is nothing more to do. But before minimising this, it should be a function of $c$ (there should be actual $c$'s in your expression for $MSE(cU)$, rather than the $c$ being $1/(n+1)$).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variance with minimal MSE in normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250333/variance-with-minimal-mse-in-normal-distribution)